# uWSGI - Serving multiple python files with only uWSGI behind nginx

Tags: python, http, nginx, uwsgi

Pardon me, this question is going to be too basic but i have not been able to get the solution anywhere. So, here goes ..

I have set up an instance nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 and an instance of uWSGI on port 9090.

I can direct the traffic from nginx to that one instance of uWSGI, and it works.

But every hello world example i see has something like this

```
> def application(env, start_response):
>         start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
>         return "Hello World From uWSGI"
```

and it is just one file... so, if i have multiple python files that needs to be served, distributed through a tree of subdirectories [basically my project]. How can I set that directory structure available for use through HTTP requests?

I would **NOT** like to use any frame work like Django of flask. But serve simple python file, similar to how a pure html site distributed through subdirectories would serve html.

i might also be missing some concept of how routing can be done. As i feel that has never come up till now.

The directory structure has logic that manipulates a database or interacts with thrid party apis.

Need some guidance to start off.

[Please let me know if there is totally a different way to archive what i am in need of, or if i am on the right track]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The application function is responsible for everything. Of you want to do routing, you do it there, by parsing the request path in `env['PATH_INFO']` and then importing and calling the relevant Python functions.

But that would be rather a silly thing to do, seeing is that is exactly what Flask would do for you. You don't need to use anything else from the framework it you really don't want to.